# Specify the parameters type without tuples

Tags: f#

I have the addition function:

```
let addition a b = a + b
```

but I want specify the types:

```
let addition(a: int, b: int): int = a + b
```

The question is I want specify the type without use a tuple to build the function. For example, with a incorrect syntax:

```
let addition a:int,b:int :int = a + b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you want is:

```
let addition (a : int) (b : int) : int = a + b
```

I've put spaces before and after each colon because that's my preference, but you don't have to have those spaces. You could also write:

```
let addition (a: int) (b: int): int = a + b
```

and that would work as well.